# how to escape a single quote (onwer's) in yaml file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a regular expression

```
   'Tid [\d]+ FAILED to get HPK lock.*tid = (?<tid>[\d]+), caller|Failed to get HPK lock [\w]+, owner's PID (?<tid>[\d]+)'
```

it is throwing a parse error at owner's

I even tried with double quotes and tried in **Online YAML Parser** but it is throwing an error

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: _"I have a regular expression"_ – no, not really. `/.../` creates a regular expression, whereas `'...'` creates a string.

Comment: Are you trying to store a string in a YAML file that can be turned into a regular expression after parsing the file?

Comment: yes exactly -- i am storing string in yaml file parsing in ruby with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an actual regular expression: (shortened for brevity)

```
re = /owner's PID (?<tid>[\d]+)/
#=> /owner's PID (?<tid>[\d]+)/
```

You can get its string representation via [`source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-i-source):

```
re.source
#=> "owner's PID (?<tid>[\\d]+)"
```

This can be used in YAML:

```
require 'yaml'
yaml = { 'pattern' => re.source }.to_yaml
#=> "---\npattern: owner's PID (?<tid>[\\d]+)\n"

puts yaml
```

Output:

```yaml
---
pattern: owner's PID (?<tid>[\d]+)
```

To parse it:

```
hash = YAML.load(yaml)
#=> {"pattern"=>"owner's PID (?<tid>[\\d]+)"}
```

And a regular expression can be created via:

```
Regexp.new(hash['pattern'])
#=> /owner's PID (?<tid>[\d]+)/
```

Note that `Regexp#source` doesn't retain the regexp's [options](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options). You might have to store them separately via [`Regexp#options`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-i-options).